# Detecting Background Process In Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-process

In window Phone 8.

While Music Player is running I just want to run the game.

On that time Game should show some popup.

Like Background Music process is running do you want to continue or stop.

or else Stop the background music of the game.

How could i do that??

Answer (score 1):

From managed you can use `MediaPlayer.GameHasControl` from the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.GameHasControl` library: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oren/archive/2010/12/02/wp7-dev-tip-detecting-whether-or-not-the-user-is-playing-music-in-the-background.aspx

Comment: S i used that. It will be working fine for Windows Phone inbuild music player. 

If i use 3rd party app. It detects the background music is playing. But, after pressing ok in the popup ("Is it ok to stop background music??")

its not responding this code(MediaPlayer.Stop()). It proceeds playing.

Anyone help to sort out this problem??